# Conjugacy for right censored data in survival analysis

Tags: survival, censoring, conjugate-prior

In survival analysis is it possible to have conjugate priors for the likelihood of right-censored data? More precisely, the likelihood of right-censored data is of the form:

$$P(X|\theta) = \Pi _{i \in \text{died}} f(x_i) \Pi _{j \in \text{lived}} S(x_j)$$

where $x_i$ are the death times for uncensored individuals and $x_j$ are the censor times for censored individuals. $S(x_j)=1-F(x_j)$ is the survival function. My understanding is that the $S(x_j)$ terms ruin conjugacy? Are there any choices of $f$ with a conjugate prior?

Comment: It all depends on the form of the functions $f$ and $S$.

Comment: @Xi'an can you provide an example of $f$ and $S$ that does have conjugacy?

Comment: The survival function of an exponential distribution comes to mind.

Comment: Is there a general statement one can make about when a likelihood with censoring will have conjugate priors? It seems like you're out of luck if the CDF of the likelihood is an integral or sum? But a simple CDF seems like a necessary but insufficient condition.